# In "Memento", why did Lenny not previously have a photo of Teddy?

Tags: memento

I've seen this question asked before, but with no real answer/opinion given.

In *Memento* (2000), Lenny takes his photo of Teddy towards the end of the black and white sequence; however, Teddy later tells Lenny that they have been working together hunting John Gs for over a year now.

If they had been working together all this time, Lenny would have surely taken a photo of Teddy by now. Which makes me think that they have actually not been working together for a year. And therefore, making Teddy's entire monologue during the climax of the film, untrustworthy.

Does anyone have any other explanation or opinion for why Lenny didn't previously have a photo of Teddy?

Comment: Perhaps Leonard has destroyed previous photos or Teddy has destroyed previous photos.